# Python odd operation?

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, operation

Can somebody please explain me why the code below behaves like it does? (It's Python in command line on Windows7 x64)

```
>>>2.22 + 0.22
2.44000000000000004
>>>(222+22)/100
2.44
```

Comment: read this : [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 5):

Floating point operations are limited in percision, and in python the limitations are well documented. You can read about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 3):

All floating point math is like this and is based on the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point oprations are known to cause errors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Use [the `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) if you want precise calculations.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the data format.

```
2.22 + 0.22 != 2.44  // both are float
// when you use them to calculate, they are giving consistently "wrong" results
// because the datatype in itself gets incorrect when moving into deep comma space
(222+22) / 100 // becomes this in calculation
222+22 = 244 --> 244/100 = 2.44
```