# This code find incorrect results

Tags: android, location, distance

Calculate the distance between 2 points based on their GeoPoint coordinates.
    find distance your location and where you want to go location .

```
 private double mesafe() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 // 6378.1 is gravity of earth
 double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371;


double latitude = 38.452261 ;
double longitude = 27.216243 ;

Location locationA = new Location("EGE");

         /*your location*/
Location lc = new Location("KONUM");

currentLat = lc.getLatitude();//your location Latitude
currentLon = lc.getLongitude(); //your location Longitude

double lat2 = currentLat;
double lon2 = currentLon;

//The difference between latitudes and longitudes
double deltalat = Math.toRadians( lat2 - latitude) ;
double deltalon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - longitude) ;
double a=Math.sin(deltalat / 2)*Math.sin(deltalat/2)+
  Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude))* Math.sin(deltalon / 2) 
                             * Math.sin(deltalon / 2);

double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 

double distance = EARTH_RADIUS*c; //find your distance

mesafee.setText(String.valueOf(distance)+"  km"); 

return distance;
  }
```

This code find distance but incorrect.

Comment: great... another question on floating point mathematics: http://floating-point-gui.de/ or here: [what every Computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python odd operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266732/python-odd-operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code using the [Haversine formular](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for distance calculation:

```
private Double calculateDistance(double lat1, final double lon1, double lat2, final double lon2) {
    final int R = 6371; // earth radius in km
    final double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    final double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    return R * c;
  }
```

Keep in mind, this is a straight-line (airline) distance of course, not a route. If you need a road-distance it's a whole different story, and you'll need some kind of routing-server. You could e.g. use Google Maps APIs, have a look at the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) or the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Comment: same code but incorrect result

Comment: Not for me, you have a different problem then. This formular is proven to work.

Comment: thank you maybe ı can not see my mistake. if you can see mistake, can you tell me?

Comment: Check your coordinates! If I use my method with your starting coordinates and a place a few meters away from it as parameters `(38.45226, 27.216243, 38.4547, 27.2158)`, I'm getting correct results.

Comment: thank you... how can ı route distance ?

Comment: and I use my location with gps incorrect result, but I take with parameter correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method,

Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(orginlat);
locationA.setLongitude(orginlong);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(tolat);
locationB.setLongitude(tolong);

Float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

Comment: same code  but incorrect result...